# QML spinner: The specific form of the text

Tags: qt, qml, transform

Image of text:

[image]

This part of the code where I want to implement it, but I can not pick up transformer correctly

```
Component {
        id: delegate
        Text {
            id: textContent
            font.pixelSize: 20;
            color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "black" : "#B2B2B2";
            text: index * 5;
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            transform: [
                Scale {
                    xScale: 0.5
                    yScale: 0.5
                    origin.x: textContent.width / 2
                    origin.y: 0
                },
                Rotation {

                    // Transform origin is the middle point of the lower border
                    origin {
                      x: textContent.width / 2
                      y: textContent.height
                    }

                    axis {x: 1; y: 0; z: 0}
                    angle: 60
                  }

            ]
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please, post minimal relevant code describes the problem. What do you mean when say "correctly" in this case?

Comment: when i said "correctly" I mean like image